# Healenium Script are not running with selenium latest version 4.1.0

Tags: json, docker, maven, automation, selenium-webdriver4

We are upgrating the selenium version 3.141.59 to 4.1.0 on the pom.xml  but it give me the null pointer exception when run the healenium script.When use selenium version 3.141.59 then script are rune fine.

Answer (score 1):

Healenium supports Selenium 4 starting from versions `3.2.0`. You need to update healenium-web version